# Google Analytics Event + eCommerce tracking => events lost

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, e-commerce

I have a site where I am successfully tracking some events, and successfully collecting eCommerce tracking data.

However, when I try to log an event together with an eCommerce transaction, the event is lost.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-XX', {'userId': 'XXX'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

... lots of html ... 

<script type="text/javascript">
ga('send', 'event', 'goal', 'purchase', "sub_plan_sku", 10.0, {'nonInteraction': 1});

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {'id':'hello_test', 'affiliation': 'example.com', 'revenue': '10.00'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {'id':'hello_test', 'name': 'sub_plan_name', 'sku': 'sub_plan_sku', 'category': 'signup', 'price': '10.00', 'quantity': '1'});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

So when I track events by themselves they work, but when I track it like above they don't get registered.

All event-tracking javascript is generated by the same Scala Class, so the precise formatting should be consistent across the two scenarios.

There are no error messages in the browser console.

The eCommerce data gets registered correctly.

???

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the `ecommerce` event with an existing event. See the note under [Load the Ecommerce Plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#loadit).

So in your situation, just move your event *after* the ecommerce event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-XX', {'userId': 'XXX'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

... lots of html ... 

<script type="text/javascript">

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {'id':'hello_test', 'affiliation': 'example.com', 'revenue': '10.00'});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {'id':'hello_test', 'name': 'sub_plan_name', 'sku': 'sub_plan_sku', 'category': 'signup', 'price': '10.00', 'quantity': '1'});
ga('ecommerce:send');

ga('send', 'event', 'goal', 'purchase', "sub_plan_sku", 10.0, {'nonInteraction': 1});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there are some bugs in your event tracking method.

1. Try to use this event tracking code without "nonInteraction"
2. Try to use only single quotes at all method
3. Try to change values like "10.0" to integer - "10".

   ga('send', 'event', 'goal', 'purchase', 'sub_plan_sku', 10);

Comment: Hi, just curious. Are these really bugs, or just preferences? I don't see any of these actually being the cause of the OP's issue. I ran the code without any problems in the console. Thanks for clarifying your answer.

Comment: Do you see results in GA Real-Time reports(Events) right after you running this code in console? If yes, then code correct, if not - code have some bugs. 
I remember cases in my practice, when events do not showing at reports because of "nonInteraction".

Comment: I actually do not see the real time event details like category, action, and label but I see it later on in the standard reports. I reported this to Google as a bug in fact. Waiting to hear back about it. In real time I however did see the moving graph with ni=1 hit, just not the details.